# Use of equals() method in HashSet

Tags: java

I read somewhere that equals() method is used to determine if two objects in HashSet are considered to be same or not.I am bit confused with my understanding.Can anyone explain the scenario please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`equals` is used to determine if the object you are trying to add or search for already exists in the `HashSet`. It's not used to determine if two objects in the `HashSet` are considered the same, since two such objects can't both be in the `HashSet`.

Comment: @Eran....Thanks for the answer.Could you please explain one more thing.....suppose we have to add {o1,o2} into the HashSet. First of all while adding o1, using hashcode() it'll find out the index in the Hash Table.Now,it will see that at that particular index nothing is stored,so it would store o1 at suppose index 1.After this it'll consider o2 and suppose using hashCode() o2 also deduces same index 1 where o1 is already stored....now equals() would come into picture and assume as of now o1 and o2 don't refer to the same object..so what will happen now? o1/o2 both get stored at 1 in chaining?

Comment: @Bhavya Yes, each index of the HashSet contains a linked list of all the elements whose hashCodes were mapped to this index.